# c++:Searching in a vector

Tags: c++, vector

I'm trying to create a pricing system for computers and I want to create two vectors, one stores item names, and  the other one, prices for the item. My plan is to have two methods, "find_item",that finds the item name inside of a vector and returns its index, and "get_itemPrice", that takes the index from find_item and gets the price. My problem is coming up with a code that takes a string object inside of a  vector  and returns its index position.

Comment: try to use `std::map` instead of `vector`. there is no problem to search for map keys

Comment: Maybe you can clarify this a bit: A) what is a "string vector"? A vector of strings? B) where do you search for it? Inside another structure? With more details, people will be able to provide better answers.

Comment: I apologize, I was in a hurry when I typed this out. See edited message ^.

Comment: @triclosan I would of used mapping but my professor recommends that I use vectors since I am learning c++(coming from a java background). I wanted to actually use both but I wanted to be consistent with my code.

Comment: @Wormhole99 as I understood your task `map`|`multimap` it's exactly what you need. You may refer `java.util.TreeMap`

Comment: @triclosan Alright, I'll use that instead. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

You can simply use [`std::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find). It will return an iterator to the first element equal to the one you are searching for, or to the `end()` if none is found. You can then use [`std::distance`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance) to get an index from that, *if* you really need it.

Comment: why? The poster asked about vectors

Comment: @Dukeling std::distance is constant time and fast for a vector, so it has negligible impact.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
vector<int> vect;
int i = 0;
for (vector<int>::iterator iter = vect.begin(); iter != vect.end(); ++iter)
{
  if (*iter == vect)
    break;
  i++;
}
if (i == vect.size())
  // not found
else
  // i is your index
```

Answer (score 0):

if you really would like to make an algorithm do it like this, but generally one should not try to beat those in the stl see the algorithm header

```
unsigned find_str( const vector<string>&  vec, const string& key ){
    unsigned count = 0;
    vector<string>::const_iterator it;
    for ( it = vec.begin() ; it < vec.end(); it++ ){
        if( *it == key)
            return count;
        count++;
    }
    /*throw not found error here.*/
}
```